# Text Extraction behavior is confusing

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

Working on storm crawler 1.13. I am using the below config for text extraction. Little confused with the way how it will works.

```
   - MAIN[role="main"]
   - DIV[id="content--news"]
   - DIV[id="content--person"]
   - ARTICLE
```

Whenever the crawler started, will it check all the tags included in the config or else it will skip the remaining tags if the first match is found.

Answer (score 0):

see [JAVADOC](http://stormcrawler.net/docs/api/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/parse/TextExtractor.html)

> The first matching inclusion pattern is used or the whole document if no expressions are configured or no match has been found.

The [code](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/parse/TextExtractor.java#L86) is pretty straight forward.